# Converting (normalizing) very small likelihood values to probability

Tags: probability, normalization, likelihood, c++, arithmetic

I am writing an algorithm where, given a model, I compute likelihoods for a list of datasets and then need to normalize (to probability) each one of the likelihood. So something like [0.00043, 0.00004, 0.00321] might be converted to may be like [0.2, 0.03, 0.77].

My problem is that the log likelihoods, I am working with, are quite small (for instance, in log space, the values are like -269647.432, -231444.981 etc). In my C++ code, when I try to add two of them (by taking their exponent) I get an answer of "Inf". I tried to add them in log-space [(Summation/Subtraction of log)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Summation.2Fsubtraction), but again stumbled upon the same problem.

Can anybody share his/her expert opinion on this?

Comment: When you used the functions you pointed to involving $\log(1+\dotsc)$, did you use the `log1p` function in your language? This uses the Taylor expansion around 1.

Comment: See also some earlier, related discussion [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56724/computation-of-likelihood-when-n-is-very-large-so-likelihood-gets-very-small/)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Subtract the maximum logarithm from all logs.  Throw away all results that are so negative they will underflow the exponential.  (Their likelihoods are, for all practical purposes, zero.)**

Indeed, if you want a relative precision of $\epsilon$ (such as $\epsilon = 10^{-d}$ for $d$ digits of precision) and you have $n$ likelihoods, throw away any result less than the logarithm of $\epsilon/n$.  Then proceed as usual to exponentiate the resulting values and divide each one by the sum of all the exponentials.

For those who like formulas, let the logarithms be $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n$ with $\lambda_n = \max(\lambda_i)$.  For logarithms to the base $b\gt 1$, define

$$\alpha_i = \cases{
b^{\lambda_i - \lambda_n}, \lambda_i - \lambda_n \ge \log(\epsilon)-\log(n) \\
0\quad \text{otherwise}.}$$

The normalized likelihoods equal $\alpha_i / \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j$, $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n.$  This works because replacing all of the otherwise underflowing $\alpha_i$ by zero makes a total error of at most $(n-1)\epsilon/n\lt \epsilon$ whereas, because $\alpha_n=b^{\lambda_n-\lambda_n}=b^0=1$ and all $\alpha_i$ are non-negative, the denominator $A = \sum_j \alpha_j \ge 1$, whence the total *relative* error due to the zero-replacement rule is strictly smaller than $\left((n-1)\epsilon/n \right) / A \lt \epsilon$, as desired.

To avoid too much rounding error, compute the sum starting with the smallest values of the $\alpha_i$.  This will be done automatically when the $\lambda_i$ are first sorted in increasing order.  This is a consideration only for very large $n$.

BTW, this prescription assumed the base of the logs is greater than $1$.  For bases $b$ less than $1$, first negate all the logs and proceed as if the base were equal to $1/b$.

---

#### Example

Let there be three values with logarithms (natural logs, say) equal to $-269647.432,$ $-231444.981,$ and $-231444.699.$  The last is the largest; subtracting it from each value gives $-38202.733,$ $-0.282,$ and $0.$

Suppose you would like precision comparable to IEEE doubles (about 16 decimal digits), so that $\epsilon=10^{-16}$ and $n=3$.  (You can't actually achieve this precision, because $-0.282$ is given only to three significant figures, but that's ok: we're only throwing away values that are guaranteed not to affect the better of the precision you want and the precision you actually have.) Compute $\log(\epsilon/n)$ = $\log(10^{-16}) - \log(3)$ = $-37.93997.$  The first of the three differences, $-38202.733,$ is less than this, so throw it away, leaving just $-0.282$ and $0.$  Exponentiating them gives $\exp(-0.282) = 0.754$ and $\exp(0)=1$ (of course).  The normalized values are--in order--$0$ for the one you threw away, $0.754 / (1 + 0.754) = 0.430$, and $1/(1+0.754)=0.570$.

Comment: This is brilliant - so simple, and so obvious in hindsight. @Ikram, please mark this as the correct answer! (unless of course you have something better, in which case please do share)

Comment: @whuber do we even need to throw away $-38202.733$? Exponentiating that gives us zero anyway, and so it won't contribute to the sum.

Comment: @Taylor exponentiating such a number yield underflow problems.

Comment: @ArturJ I suspect Taylor might have been doing the computation in `R` or some other platform that replaces such underflows with zeros.  That behavior is convenient but dangerous: you really need to understand what's going on in your algorithm before you have any right to rely on it.

Comment: good point whuber! @ArturJ as far as I can tell, [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow#Handling_of_underflow) *doesn't* say anything about what to do in the case of underflow, just that it has to be signaled: "[t]he occurrence of an underflow may set a ("sticky") status bit, raise an exception, at the hardware level generate an interrupt, or may cause some combination of these effects." I shouldn't have been relying on the rounding