# weights versus shifted log-weights

Tags: logarithm, particle-filter

I'm having a hard time checking an equality in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.01707.pdf. It is unnumbered, immediately before (24), on page 13. Any help would be appreciated. Here is some simplified notation and a simplified question.

Let

1. $v^{(i)} > 0$ be the unnormalized weights
2. $v_{\text{max}} = \max_i\{\log v^{(i)}\}$
3. $\tilde{v}^i = \log v^{(i)} - v_{\text{max}}$ the shifted log-weights
4. $i=1,\ldots,N$

Usually we want to calculate $\frac{1}{N}\sum_i v^{(i)}$. But they're saying it's more numerically stable to calculate 
$$
\log \left[ \frac{1}{N}\sum_i v^{(i)} \right] = v_{\text{max}} + \left[\sum_i \tilde{v}^i \right]- \log N.
$$
Problem is I'm not getting that.

\begin{align*}
\log \left[ \frac{1}{N}\sum_i v^{(i)} \right] &= - \log N + \log\left[\sum_i v^{(i)} \right] \\
&= - \log N + \log\left[\sum_i \exp \log v^{(i)} \right] \\
&= - \log N + \log\left[\sum_i \exp \left\{\log v^{(i)} + v_{\text{max}} - v_{\text{max}} \right\}\right] \\
&= - \log N + \log\left[\sum_i \exp \left\{ \tilde{v}^{(i)} + v_{\text{max}} \right\}\right] \\
&= - \log N + \log\left[\exp v_{\text{max}} \sum_i \exp  \tilde{v}^{(i)}  \right] \\
&= - \log N + v_{\text{max}} + \log\left[ \sum_i \exp  \tilde{v}^{(i)}  \right] \\
&\neq - \log N + v_{\text{max}} + \log\left[ \exp \sum_i  \tilde{v}^{(i)}  \right] \tag{?}\\
&= v_{\text{max}} + \left[\sum_i \tilde{v}^i \right]- \log N.
\end{align*}

1. What am I missing here?
2. Why is it more numerically stable? Why are floating points numbers better approximations to real numbers when the real numbers are not super small?

Comment: @JarleTufto this looks like a pretty good answer to me. Feel free to make it official. Also, I confirmed that it is a typo with one of the authors.

Comment: Ok, I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what is needed is $\log(\frac1N\sum v^{(i)})$ and computing each $v^{(i)}$ would result in numerical underflow ($v^{(i)}$ becomes numerically equal to zero) a trick like this is needed. Your expression $- \log N + v_{\text{max}} + \log\left[ \sum_i \exp  \tilde{v}^{(i)}  \right]$ would then solve the problem because $\exp \tilde v^{(i)}$ will not underflow (and the expression given by the authors indeed looks wrong). But if these numbers are sufficiently far from underflowing (greater than about $2^{-1022 + 52}$) I agree with you that nothing would be gained.

Apparently, the above numerical approach is known as the log-sum-exp trick for log-domain calculations, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogSumExp and [What to do when your likelihood function has a double product with small values near zero - log transform doesn't work?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142254/what-to-do-when-your-likelihood-function-has-a-double-product-with-small-values/142331#142331)

Comment: ah okay, now that I know what I'm looking for, it makes more sense to exponentiate $\tilde{v}^{(i)}$. Couldn't we also run into problems if all $\{ v^{(i)}\}$, including the maximum, are too close to zero? Then the $\tilde{v}^{(i)}$ would still be too close to zero, only negative this time.

Comment: @Taylor I haven't looked at the paper on arxiv but I guess the idea is that that this trick applies if you can work with everything in terms of logs.  So then you don't run into problems with underflow.  I added a link to a wikipedia page describing the trick in my answer.